# Creating a new locale on craft 2, entries won't load

Tags: localization

I have an issue creating a new locale, I already have two set up 'en_gb' and 'en_au' and have added a third 'fr'.

I have added the new locale to general.php:

```
'.com' => array(
  'siteUrl' => array(
        'en_gb' => 'https://xxx.com/',
        'en_au' => 'https://xxx.com/au/',
        'fr' => 'https://xxx.com/fr/'
    ),
  'devMode' => false
),
```

And have enabled that locale on the section with exactly the same settings as the others:

[image]

When I switch to the French locale on an entry I can live preview without a problem, but when I actually publish the page and visit it the entry cannot be found.

I'm well and truly stumped on why I can't access the published page.

When creating the locale I did have issues with failed tasks re-saving entries which I spent a lot of time trying to debug with [this guide](https://craftcms.com/support/stuck-tasks) without luck and with less hair. Would this be a cause considering the locale shows on an entry and the live preview works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `/fr/` directory created in your public_html folder?
https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/localization-guide.html#step-5-set-up-the-files

Maybe try making a totally new entry for all 3 locales.

Comment: This is of course the correct answer, thank you so so much, I'm an idiot.